# Gradle not recognizing springboot buildInfo plugin

Tags: spring-boot, gradle-plugin, spring-boot-actuator, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to add the `springboot` `buildInfo` plugin to my `build.gradle.kts` so I can generate the `build-info.properties` file and expose the build info (i.e. app version) via the `/actuator/info` endpoint. However, I keep getting the following error when I add the buildInfo plugin:

`Unresolved reference: springBoot`

I've been referencing the following [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#integrating-with-actuator), but it just says to simply add the plugin and build.

Am I placing the plugin in the right spot in my gradle file? Do I need another dependency or plugin reference to get this working?

Here is what the main part of my `build.gradle.kts` looks like:

```
group = "com.walmart.muse.core-kt"
version = getLatestTagVersion()
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.0.RELEASE" apply false
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.3.50"
}

// This little code block is what is causing the error. 
// I want to use it to get buid-info.properties so I can hit `/actuator/info` 
// to expose my build info, but this isn't working :(
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven(url = "https://my-company's-repository.com") // edited for privacy
    }

    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")
    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen")
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring")
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa")
    apply(plugin = "kotlin-spring")

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
        implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api-kotlin:1.0.0")
        implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0")
        implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0")
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
        implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
        implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4")

        runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6")

        testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
        testImplementation("com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0")
        testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
            exclude(module = "junit")
        }

        testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    }

    allOpen {
        annotation("javax.persistence.Entity")
        annotation("javax.persistence.Embeddable")
        annotation("javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass")
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }

    tasks.withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Reason is, that you used `apply` and as statted by gradle doc https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin_using_standard_api now gradle-kotlin-dsl can't use type safe accessors.

Instead of

```
springBoot {
   buildInfo()
}
```

in your `build.gradle.kts` you have to use

```
configure<org.springframework.boot.gradle.dsl.SpringBootExtension> {
  buildInfo()
}
```